# aws bucket policy editor - Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use the policy editor.
I then try and apply the policy I just created in the wizard but I get the above error

[image]

Comment: GetObject applies to objects. You've supplied a bucket as the resource.

Answer (score 2):

First get the bucket ARN.  You can get this by clicking on the bucket row - but NOT the bucket link in that row.  Which can be confusing to first timers.  When you click on the row (but NOT the link) you get a bucket info panel with a 'Copy bucket ARN' button which is very handy.  See here:
[image]

You paste it into the ARN field:

[image]

When you then generate the policy you will get something like this:

[image]

### Here is the **critical part**

### Once you have copied this, you need to add "/*" at the end of the resource (the S3 bucket), like this:

[image]

Finally you will get  this message indicating that the operation succeeded

[image]